# How to Get Center Location Latitude And Longitude of Google map in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

i am newbie in iOS Development and new in map kit i want to know about Latitude and Longitude of MapView Center Every time Like as When User Scrollfrom one location to Another then i want to Show Center Latitude and Longitude of my GMSMapView how it Possible like as Here i Attach Image for it.

Here my Current Location is Mumbai Then It Shows My mapView like as

[image]

and i want to know Center Location Latitude and Longitude like as when user Scroll Mapview then i want to Know Latitude and Longitude of My Image Indicator Point. Here image Show as i want to Know Latitude and Longitude of this Point Here My Image indicated is in Center Position of my MapView.

[image]

Comment: did you get the answer? have you solved the issue then please put the answer here.

Answer (score 7):

To get the position whenever the map is moved, you'd want to handle `mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:`.

Then inside that method, you can access `mapView.camera.target` to get the current centre of the map.

```
- (void) mapView: (GMSMapView *)mapView 
     didChangeCameraPosition: (GMSCameraPosition *)position 
{
    double latitude = mapView.camera.target.latitude;
    double longitude = mapView.camera.target.longitude;

    // now do something with latitude and longitude
}
```

Note that to handle the delegate method, you'll need to implement the [`GMSMapViewDelegate` protocol](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p). When setting up the map, you'd need to set the map's delegate to the class which handles the protocol (usually `self`), eg:

```
mapView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Please Can you give me Any Resource for it?

Comment: here i not Change location then it is worked? here i only move my map view. then it was worked?

Answer (score 2):

Use below code for getting center of mapview latitude and longitude  .
  When ever you scroll mapview in any direction automatically  **regionWillChangeAnimated:** method will call.It's one of the optinal delegate method.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
     CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(mkmapView.centerCoordinate.latitude, mkmapView.centerCoordinate.longitude);
     CGFloat txtLatitude = coord.latitude;
     CGFloat txtLongitude = coord.longitude;
     NSLog(@"Latitude is===>>>%f %f",txtLongitude);
     NSLog(@"Longitude is===>>>%f %f",txtLongitude);
 }
```

If you tap the map view,you need that **Latitude** and **Longitude** use below code.
Here **_mkMapView** is outlet of Mapview.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture= [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(backgroundTapped:)];
     [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
}

- (void)backgroundTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [gesture locationInView:_mkMapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location =[_mkMapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:_mkMapView];
}
```

may be it will helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)pMapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {
mapViewRef.delegate = self;
double latitude = mapViewRef.camera.target.latitude;
double longitude = mapViewRef.camera.target.longitude;
CLLocationCoordinate2D addressCoordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
GMSGeocoder* coder = [[GMSGeocoder alloc] init];
[coder reverseGeocodeCoordinate:addressCoordinates completionHandler:^(GMSReverseGeocodeResponse *results, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        // NSLog(@"Error %@", error.description);
    } else {
        GMSAddress* address = [results firstResult];
        NSArray *arr = [address valueForKey:@"lines"];
        NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[arr count]];
        if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
            self.txtPlaceSearch.text = @"";
        }
        else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            NSString *str2 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            self.txtPlaceSearch.text = str2;
        }
        else if ([str1 isEqualToString:@"2"]) {
            NSString *str2 = [arr objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *str3 = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
            self.txtPlaceSearch.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@,%@",str2,str3];
        }
    }
  }];
}
```